# What does "had no business" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> The U.S. **had no business** dropping points, much less losing. And yet it
>   did.

What's the meaning of *had no business* here?

Is it like *did not need at all*? *Or were not interested in*? Or *by all means had to avoid*? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**have no business**  can be used in a wide variety of circumstances all of which could be paraphrased as "X should not be happening".  Sometimes it is used "tongue-in-cheek", as with the first example below:

> She has no business being so pretty and distracting everyone.
>
> You have no business being here after the building has been locked.
>
> The country has no business supporting rebel militias.

Answer (score 1):

Your last suggestion seems to have a close meaning:

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have-no-business-doing-sth